Why the colour displayed on screen isn't the colour set in `draw(_:)` with CoreGraphics?
I want to display a colour bar with colours I do compute.
I check the return of my function computing colour mapValueToRGB, which seems to properly compute the colour. But on screen I don't see the returned colour.
Below is an illustration of this problem. On the 244th pixel, I should have something very close to pure red, but I get (233, 51, 35) : Screenshot of wrong color on screen
Here is the piece of code in draw(_:) function :
guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return }
context.setLineWidth(1)
for y in 0..<Int(frame.height) {
    let p = CGFloat(y)/frame.height
    let color = mapValueToRGB(value: p, minMax: minMax, colorsMap: colors)
    print(y, color)

    context.setStrokeColor(color)
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: xStart, y: y))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xEnd, y: y))
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
}

And here is the console output :
y: 242 <CGColor 0x600001b60ba0> (...) ( 0.99384 0 0 1 )
y: 243 <CGColor 0x600001b60c00> (...) ( 0.997947 0 0 1 )
y: 244 <CGColor 0x600001b60c60> (...) ( 1 0.00205339 0.00205339 1 )
y: 245 <CGColor 0x600001b60cc0> (...) ( 1 0.00616016 0.00616016 1 )

The colour seems to be properly computed, but is not the colour displayed on screen.
EDIT
Problem resolved thanks to the help in comments.
guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return }
context.setLineWidth(1)
for y in 0..<Int(frame.height) {
    let p = CGFloat(y)/frame.height
    let components: simd_float4 = mapValueToRGB(value: p, minMax: minMax, colorsMap: colors)
    let color = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: [CGFloat(components.x), CGFloat(components.y), CGFloat(components.z), CGFloat(components.w)])
          
    context.setStrokeColor(color!)
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: xStart, y: y))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xEnd, y: y))        
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
}


What is the colorSpace of the CGContext? See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363722/180716

You'll need to show mapValueToRGB. You're likely doing it in a way that doesn't consider the colorspace. Computing based on a linear RGB colorspace isn't going to display correctly on a real screen.

Thank you @Sweeper for your comment. The context.colorSpace is nil. For right now, I tried to set this context.setStrokeColorSpace(CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.genericRGBLinear)!) and it has no effect.

Thank you @RobNapier for your comment. Indeed, I didn't consider colorspace. My fonction is a basic linear interpolation : (1-p)componentA + pcomponentB. The numeric colorimeter returns pure red if I display the SRGB values instead of native values.
